# C# Program Calling Stored procedure that executes bcp command is giving timeout

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, bcp

I have a stored procedure that exports data to a text file by using bcp command. When I execute this stored procedure individually, it executes perfectly fine in less than a minute. However, When I call this stored procedure from a ASP.NET C# code, it takes huge amount of time and eventually results in timeout exception. 
Can you please help me on solving this issue.

Following is the piece of code that dumps the data to a text file.

```
SET @DynamicSQL = 'bcp "select Line from [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]" queryout "' 
              + @FolderPath + '\' + @FileName + '" -c -t, -T -S' + @ServerInstanceName  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @DynamicSQL
```

Thanks 
Srini

Comment: why don't you call the stored procedure directly from C# then vs trying to dynamically build it.. it's obvious you are doing something incorrect.. can you post the actual stored procedure

Comment: The above code resides in a stored procedure only. And I am calling this stored procedure from ASP.NET page.

Comment: can you post your code that is calling the stored proc?

Comment: objCommand.Connection = objConn;
                objCommand.CommandText = "spExportData";
                objCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCommand.CommandTimeout = 1200;

  /* Here the prameter list */

                nResult = objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Above is the C# code that I am using to call the stored procedure "spExportData". In side "spExportData", I am calling bcp command (as described in the original question) to dump to a text file. When I call the stored procedure directly inside SSMS, I am getting the file in less than a minute. However, when I call the stored procedure from above C# program, it is taking more than 20 minutes and giving timeout issue. Please let me know what wrong I am doing in this case.